# What does `cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1` mean?

Tags: powershell

I've been experimenting with creating files in the visual studio terminal which defaults to powershell and have been using `cat` and `echo` to create new files, but both bring up the message:

```
cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
```

`echo` then requests values for:

```
InputObject[0]:
InputObject[1]:
etc.
```

Whereas `cat` asks for:

```
Path[0]:
Path[1]:
etc.
```

What does this actually mean?

Comment: If you supply no values when calling `echo` or `cat`, you get this prompt because there are mandatory parameters for each command.

Comment: `Write-Output` needs at least one thing to actually write. If you give it nothing, it will start asking. To create an empty file (i.e. actually write nothing at all, similar to `touch`) you can use `Set-Content -Path xxx -Value $null`. `Write-Output $null` is also allowed, of course.

Comment: So are `InputObject` and `Path` asking for values to enter into the file? Because nothing I enter against them gets written to it, and I cannot get the command to end without pressing ctrl+c

Comment: `InputObject` asks for the value to write, while `Path` asks for the name of the file.

Comment: @askman Hit enter twice to signal you have no more input to provide

Comment: cat is an alias for Get-Content.  echo is an alias for Write-Output.  This can be misleading.  They don't work exactly the same way cat and echo work in Unix.  You need to learn how they actually work.  You also need to learn how pipelines actually work.  PS pipelines are object oriented.  This is a lot more powerful than character-oriented pipelines are.  But the learning curve is steep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat` (Getting content) has a mandatory parameter of `path` which is why it is asking for to put the path to what file for example you would like to `cat`

Same principle applies to `echo` (writing output) as you're telling it to `echo` nothing it will prompt you for some input so it can actually run the command as intended.

In powershell `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` Is what you can use yourself to test this out further